# Changing unit of measure of Draw tool in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, units

[image]

How do I change the unit of measure when using the drawing tool in ArcMap 10.5.1, like indicated in image?

Comment: What is preventing you from using the Picture button to present your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These measures seem to follow the setting for Map Display Units. Right click on the map, select *Data Frame Properties* and then select the *General* tab to change this.